# what is the type for a function inside of prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript

I currently have the following prop inside a component:

```
 styles={{
            placeholder: () => ({
              height: 16,
              fontSize: 14,
              lineHeight: 1.14,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              color: '#5c6f7b',
            }),
          }}
```

In typescript I'm getting an error:

```
Type '{ placeholder: () => { height: number; fontSize: number; lineHeight: number; fontFamily: string; color: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
```

if I change the type to any it removes the redlines. but what is the more accurate type for this?
I've tried string | number but didnt help

Comment: You are giving an object function to placeholder?

Comment: Yes you can look into React select if you'd like @RitikBanger

Answer (score 1):

You can type styles as this:

```js
{
  placeholder: () => React.CSSProperties
}
```